# Ubuntu 22.04 Boot Order Prefers Low Latency Over Generic Kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 22.04

Ever since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 I've been having a problem after running update-grub; the low latency kernel is being picked as the preferred version at the top of the GRUB menu over the "generic" version.

Question: How do I always make the latest generic kernel the top choice in the GRUB menu?

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

After digging around in the scripts that update-grub uses that are in /etc/grub.d
and specifically 10_linux, I finally found a solution.

- Make copies of both /etc/default/grub and /boot/grub/grub.cfg in case something goes haywire.
- sudo nano /etc/default/grub
- Add the line: GRUB_FLAVOUR_ORDER="generic" to the bottom of the file and save.
- sudo update-grub
- Before rebooting, you can visually verify that the generic kernel is the top menu item by opening /boot/grub/grub.cfg in an editor and looking at the first instance of "menuentry" and making sure that the generic kernel is in there.

That's the fix.

The reason for all this is:

10_linux uses the library /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib,
which has this function: version_find_latest, which in turn calls version_test_gt to determine the latest version.

When GRUB_FLAVOUR_ORDER="generic" is set in /etc/default/grub, version_test_gt contains logic to give priority to the "generic" kernel when sudo update-grub is run.