# Unable to boot in low latency after kernel upgrade - Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: boot, kernel, ubuntu-studio

I'm on a new machine a couple of weeks old:
Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IAH7 Type 82S9 |
12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-12450H × 12 |
NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile].

I configured it to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.
Then, I used the Ubuntu Studio Installer to install all Ubuntu Studio components, including the low latency kernel.
Everything was working as expected, even though I hadn't installed the NVIDIA driver and was using the default open-source one instead.

A few days ago, I was prompted to upgrade some stuff (I think it was Core 22) and I noticed that the kernel was upgraded.
As a result, I haven't been able to boot with "Ubuntu (lowlatency)" since. The screen goes black after the boot dialog.

I can still boot with "Ubuntu (generic)" and with "Windows 11", though.

What I've tried, so far:

- I installed the NVIDIA driver ... (proprietary, tested);
- I booted into Ubuntu recovery mode and tried updating the grub bootloader;

While in recovery mode, I was able to check the following information (which didn't change with the update attempt):

- generic 5.19.0-46
- lowlatency 5.15.0-76

Is anyone having the same issue? And how to solve it?
I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: no matter what I did, `generic` kernel was always used, no matter what Grub options I modified, including stuff that worked for older Ubuntu versions.

I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1432730/288581). It's a matter of setting `GRUB_FLAVOUR_ORDER` with the desired "kernel flavor" in `/etc/default/grub`, update Grub and reboot. Something like this (with `sudo`):

```
$ echo 'GRUB_FLAVOUR_ORDER="lowlatency" | tee -a /etc/default/grub
$ update-grub
$ reboot
```

Hope it helps.