# Linux low latency not loading to desktop in Ubuntu 23.10 (generic Linux does)

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-geforce

I installed Ubuntu 23.10 fresh on my PC and now the option with Linux low-latency won't load to desktop. The same PC was booting with Linux low latency without problems on 23.04 and earlier Ubuntu versions. The option with generic (default) Linux on 23.10 works as well.

It's the first time I get this problem and I haven't been able to find any hints online. Maybe is it related to NVidia drivers? I don't even know where to look to understand the problem, even less to solve it. I submitted [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lowlatency/+bug/2043469) including boot logs.

As I'm typing this post, AskUbuntu suggests one question that might be related, but it is unanswered: [Unable to boot in low latency after kernel upgrade - Ubuntu 22.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478193/unable-to-boot-in-low-latency-after-kernel-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04-2)

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this problem thanks to a hint received in [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lowlatency/+bug/2043469). Looking at the boot log, the problem was that the configuration was booting to Nouveau (open source) instead of the corresponding Nvidia driver (even if it was installed). The cause of this is still unclear, but this is is how the problem can be solved:

First, check in the command line what Nvidia drivers are recommended for your graphics card:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You will get an output similar to this:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013C0sv0000196Esd00001116bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM204 [GeForce GTX 980]
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Try to install the `recommended` driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX
```

(Change "XXX" for the version number.)

In my case, the system reported that this driver was already installed. In that case, one solution is to install the next version in the list (skipping the "-server" options).

Once it is installed, reboot. Chances are that the booting process will load the desktop now.

Yes? Try the recommended and previously installed version again. In my case it worked!

No? Try a lower version. If you had your card working with low-latency in the past, you should be able to find a functional driver version again.