# Why does my system come up in the UEFI instead of Ubuntu 22.04 now?

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, uefi, zfs

## Background

My system has been chugging along for a year (or more) and recently, after re-boot, Ubuntu 22.04 did not come up and eventually it settled inside the UEFI BIOS. Hitting `ESC` at boot takes me to the Grub menu which only has one entry to enter the UEFI BIOS. I can enter Grub's command line and typing the commands below, I can boot into Linux. (It doesn't seem like this should be necessary. Somehow the mechanism to auto-boot is gone.)

```
grub> set root=(hd1,gpt3)
grub> linux /BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/@/vmlinuz root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw boot=zfs
grub> initrd /BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/@/initrd.img
grub> boot
```

The question is why aren't these commands in the boot configuration to automatically bring up the system? What caused it to suddenly stop booting? I have the Ubuntu PRO service. Did it update something that broke the booting?

## Work-around

I still have not figured out what changed in my system to cause a boot to the UEFI BIOS. However, with community help, I've got a work-around.

Based on comments, I have created a new boot menu entry in the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` configuration file containing the proper grub commands to boot to Linux. Additionally, that new menu item is set as the default.

Here is my new `/etc/default/grub` file which selects the default menu item. Note that the UEFI firmware menu item is #0. Since the `40_custom` is run later, it will be at menu item #1.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
 
GRUB_DEFAULT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash resume=UUID=2ea078a9-4754-4da5-a869-b70baf650372"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
 
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
 
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768,auto
 
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
 
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
 
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The `40_custom` script contains this new menu entry:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Special Boot' $menuentry_id_option 'Ubuntu-Linux-22dot04' {
set root=(hd1,gpt3)
linux /BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/@/vmlinuz root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw boot=zfs
initrd /BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/@/initrd.img
boot
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

After making these changes, running `sudo update-grub` and `sudo install-grub`, I can at least get an automatic boot again.

But I still don't have any answers to my question(s) about what caused this problem to begin with.

## Machine Info

The machine has two drives: `nvme0n1` (2TiB nvme ssd) and `sda` (1 TiB SATA SSD -- recently added for SWAP on `sda1` and backup `sda2`). `nvme0n1` has 4 partitions for a ZFS filesystem where Linux is located.

The `boot-repair` utility will only supply the following report, but will not fix anything because I can't seem to decrypt the `nvme0n1p2` partition for it. (I doubt this is critical as it was a very small swap space that is not disabled in the /etc/fstab.)

```
    boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20231016_1119]
     
    ============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================
     
    => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
    => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
     
    nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________
     
        File system:       vfat
        Boot sector type:  FAT32
        Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        /grub.cfg
     
    nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________
     
        File system:       crypto_LUKS
        Boot sector type:  Unknown
        Boot sector info: 
     
    nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________
     
        File system:       zfs_member
        Boot sector type:  -
        Boot sector info: 
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        
     
    nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________
     
        File system:       zfs_member
        Boot sector type:  -
        Boot sector info: 
        Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
        Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub
     
    sda1: __________________________________________________________________________
     
        File system:       swap
        Boot sector type:  -
        Boot sector info: 
     
    sda2: __________________________________________________________________________
     
        File system:       ext4
        Boot sector type:  -
        Boot sector info: 
        Operating System:  
        Boot files:        
     
     
    ================================ 1 OS detected =================================
     
    OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS CurrentSession on rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw
     
    ================================ Host/Hardware =================================
     
    CPU architecture: 64-bit
    Video: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] EFI VGA from NVIDIA Corporation
    BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
    /BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/@/vmlinuz root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw boot=zfs
    df -Th / : rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw zfs   1.8T  206G  1.6T  12% /
     
    ===================================== UEFI =====================================
     
    BIOS/UEFI firmware: 3803(5.13) from American Megatrends Inc.
    The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
    SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
    BootCurrent: 0000
    Timeout: 1 seconds
    BootOrder: 0000
    Boot0000* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,98401b0a-7aef-4108-8ba2-32b2726657bd,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
     
     
    ============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================
     
    Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________
     
    nvme0n1 : is-GPT, no-BIOSboot, has---ESP, not-usb, not-mmc, no-os, no-wind, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
    sda : is-GPT, no-BIOSboot, has-noESP, not-usb, not-mmc, no-os, no-wind, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
     
    Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________
     
    nvme0n1p3 : no-os, 64, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, grubenv-ok, noupdategrub, not-far
    nvme0n1p1 : no-os, 64, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far
    nvme0n1p4 : no-os, 64, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, farbios
    sda2 : no-os, 64, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, farbios
    mapper/keystore-rpool : no-os, 64, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far
     
    Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________
     
    nvme0n1p3 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
    nvme0n1p1 : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
    nvme0n1p4 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
    sda2 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
    mapper/keystore-rpool : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
     
    Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________
     
    nvme0n1p3 : is--zfs-boot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, nvme0n1
    nvme0n1p1 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, nvme0n1
    nvme0n1p4 : maybesepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, nvme0n1
    sda2 : maybesepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sda
    mapper/keystore-rpool : maybesepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sda
     
    fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________
     
    Disk nvme0n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
    Disk identifier: 10CE2001-F2D1-43C4-AF9E-40C33E6E309C
                Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
    nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
    nvme0n1p2 1050624    5244927    4194304    2G Linux swap
    nvme0n1p3 5244928    9439231    4194304    2G Solaris boot
    nvme0n1p4 9439232 3907029134 3897589903  1.8T Solaris root
    Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
    Disk identifier: BD95CBE7-5BC6-453C-966F-0CCBF1A71129
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
    sda1       2048  270534655  270532608   129G Linux swap
    sda2  270534656 1953523711 1682989056 802.5G Linux filesystem
    Disk zd0: 500 MiB, 524288000 bytes, 1024000 sectors
    Disk mapper/keystore-rpool: 484 MiB, 507510784 bytes, 991232 sectors
    Disk mapper/cryptoswap: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
     
    parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________
     
    sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA WD Blue SA510 2.:;
    1:1049kB:139GB:139GB:linux-swap(v1):swap:swap;
    2:139GB:1000GB:862GB:ext4:Backup-01:;
    mapper/cryptoswap:2147MB:dm:512:512:unknown:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;
    mapper/keystore-rpool:508MB:dm:512:8192:loop:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;
    1:0.00B:508MB:508MB:ext4::;
    nvme0n1:2000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:CT2000P3SSD8:;
    1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
    2:538MB:2685MB:2147MB:::swap;
    3:2685MB:4833MB:2147MB:zfs::;
    4:4833MB:2000GB:1996GB:zfs::;
    zd0:524MB:unknown:512:8192:unknown:Unknown:;
     
    blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________
     
    NAME             FSTYPE      UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL          PARTLABEL
    sda                                                                                                                   
    ├─sda1           swap        2ea078a9-4754-4da5-a869-b70baf650372 c3dbb487-4201-441e-91f4-537e5c9d3023                swap
    └─sda2           ext4        78ddbdfd-a265-4815-8253-f21ebd8fa790 2b414450-1fb4-4dd6-ae90-08dbfdd452e2 BKUP01         Backup-01
    zd0              crypto_LUKS b3c40e1f-922f-4119-86be-6c1cafa28df1                                                     
    └─keystore-rpool ext4        00873c9b-be59-48a3-8228-9175847bff29                                      keystore-rpool 
    nvme0n1                                                                                                               
    ├─nvme0n1p1      vfat        623E-2F75                            98401b0a-7aef-4108-8ba2-32b2726657bd                EFI System Partition
    ├─nvme0n1p2      crypto_LUKS 0499446b-d22f-4496-9443-63134aa6ff4e 165bf710-ba55-4b47-b393-3558a548ec66                
    │ └─cryptoswap                                                                                                        
    ├─nvme0n1p3      zfs_member  5837193240244028344                  9624a9b8-596c-d244-825b-1799db0a550c bpool          
    └─nvme0n1p4      zfs_member  2872672152338174268                  3db24d13-0e32-9243-a929-5a45392d5306 rpool          
     
    Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________
     
                                                      Avail Use% Mounted on
    bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw                           1.3G  26% /boot
    /dev/mapper/keystore-rpool                       403.1M   0% /run/keystore/rpool
    /dev/nvme0n1p1[/grub]                            496.7M   3% /boot/grub
    /dev/sda2                                        725.1G   3% /media/backup
    //redwood/d-drive                                826.5G  11% /media/redwood_d_drive
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw                           1.5T  12% /
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/srv                       1.5T   0% /srv
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/usr/local                 1.5T   0% /usr/local
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/games                 1.5T   0% /var/games
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib                   1.5T   0% /var/lib
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/AccountsService   1.5T   0% /var/lib/AccountsService
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/apt               1.5T   0% /var/lib/apt
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/dpkg              1.5T   0% /var/lib/dpkg
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/NetworkManager    1.5T   0% /var/lib/NetworkManager
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/log                   1.5T   0% /var/log
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/mail                  1.5T   0% /var/mail
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/snap                  1.5T   0% /var/snap
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/spool                 1.5T   0% /var/spool
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/www                   1.5T   0% /var/www
    rpool/USERDATA/root_mtocmd                         1.5T   0% /root
    rpool/USERDATA/tdavis_mtocmd                       1.5T   1% /home/tdavis
     
    Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________
     
     
    ============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================
     
    /dev/mapper:
    control
    cryptoswap
    keystore-rpool
     
    ======================== nvme0n1p1/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================
     
    ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
    UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
    ### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
     
    ================= nvme0n1p1: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================
     
               GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
                ?? = ??             grub.cfg                                       1
     
    ================= nvme0n1p3: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================
     
               GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
                ?? = ??             vmlinuz
                ?? = ??             vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic
                ?? = ??             vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic
                ?? = ??             vmlinuz.old
                ?? = ??             initrd.img
                ?? = ??             initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic
                ?? = ??             initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic
                ?? = ??             initrd.img.old
     
    ======================== nvme0n1p4/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================
     
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    # /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
    UUID=623E-2F75  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022      0       1
    /boot/efi/grub /boot/grub none defaults,bind 0 0
    UUID=2ea078a9-4754-4da5-a869-b70baf650372 none swap sw   0       0
    //redwood/d-drive /media/redwood_d_drive cifs credentials=/home/tdavis/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0
    UUID=78ddbdfd-a265-4815-8253-f21ebd8fa790 /media/backup ext4 defaults 0 0
     
    ==================== nvme0n1p4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================
     
    GRUB_DEFAULT=0
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
    GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768,auto
     
    ================= nvme0n1p4: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================
     
               GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
                ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz
                ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic
                ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic
                ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz.old
                ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img
                ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic
                ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic
                ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img.old
     
    =================== nvme0n1p4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================
     
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2022 40_custom
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom
     
    ======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================
     
    Unknown BootLoader on nvme0n1p2
     
     
    ================================= User choice ==================================
     
    Is there RAID on this computer? no
     
     
     
    ====================== Installed session with Root on ZFS ======================
     
    zpool list NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
    bpool  1.88G   462M  1.42G        -         -     0%    24%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
    rpool  1.81T   243G  1.57T        -         -     3%    13%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
     
    SOURCE                                           FSTYPE                   SIZE   USED  AVAIL USE% TARGET
    /dev/mapper/keystore-rpool                       ext4                     437M    28K 403.1M   0% /run/keystore/rpool
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw                         zfs                      1.7T 205.9G   1.5T  12% /
    rpool/USERDATA/tdavis_mtocmd                     zfs                      1.5T    11G   1.5T   1% /home/tdavis
    rpool/USERDATA/root_mtocmd                       zfs                      1.5T  95.3M   1.5T   0% /root
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/srv                     zfs                      1.5T   384K   1.5T   0% /srv
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/usr/local               zfs                      1.5T   133M   1.5T   0% /usr/local
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/games               zfs                      1.5T   256K   1.5T   0% /var/games
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib                 zfs                      1.5T   5.3G   1.5T   0% /var/lib
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/log                 zfs                      1.5T 812.1M   1.5T   0% /var/log
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/spool               zfs                      1.5T   5.5M   1.5T   0% /var/spool
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/mail                zfs                      1.5T   256K   1.5T   0% /var/mail
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/snap                zfs                      1.5T   4.8M   1.5T   0% /var/snap
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/www                 zfs                      1.5T   256K   1.5T   0% /var/www
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/NetworkManager  zfs                      1.5T   384K   1.5T   0% /var/lib/NetworkManager
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/AccountsService zfs                      1.5T   256K   1.5T   0% /var/lib/AccountsService
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/apt             zfs                      1.5T 164.5M   1.5T   0% /var/lib/apt
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/var/lib/dpkg            zfs                      1.5T  90.8M   1.5T   0% /var/lib/dpkg
    /dev/sda2                                        ext4                   788.9G  23.6G 725.1G   3% /media/backup
    bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw                         zfs                      1.7G 459.6M   1.3G  26% /boot
    /dev/nvme0n1p1                                   vfat                     511M  14.3M 496.7M   3% /boot/efi
    /dev/nvme0n1p1[/grub]                            vfat                     511M  14.3M 496.7M   3% /boot/grub
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw[/usr/share/hunspell]    zfs                      1.7T 205.9G   1.5T  12% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
    //redwood/d-drive                                cifs                   931.4G 104.8G 826.5G  11% /media/redwood_d_drive
     
     
     
     
    Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________
     
    The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
     
    Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________
     
    You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 myvolume)
    Are you sure you want to continue anyway?
```

I ran `update-grub` and this is the result:

```
    root@birch:/etc/default# update-grub
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg'
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw
    Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw
    Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw
    Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw
    Warning: didn't find any valid initrd or kernel.
    Warning: didn't find any valid initrd or kernel.
    Warning: didn't find any valid initrd or kernel.
    Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
    Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
    Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
    Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
    Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
```

It is the last line that bothers me as there is no entry for Linux.

The `/etc/default/grub` configuration seems pretty benign too.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
 
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash resume=UUID=2ea078a9-4754-4da5-a869-b70baf650372"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
 
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
 
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768,auto
 
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
 
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
 
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Also, worth noting that the CFM mode is disabled.

After running `update-grub` I check to see if files where changing in the mount /boot/efi folder. The time stamps changed to the moment I ran the command:

```
    tdavis@birch:~$ tree -pD /boot/efi
    [drwxr-xr-x Dec 31  1969]  /boot/efi
    ├── [drwxr-xr-x Dec 12  2022]  EFI
    │   ├── [drwxr-xr-x Dec 12  2022]  BOOT
    │   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  BOOTX64.EFI
    │   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  fbx64.efi
    │   │   └── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  mmx64.efi
    │   └── [drwxr-xr-x Dec 12  2022]  ubuntu
    │       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  BOOTX64.CSV
    │       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  grub.cfg
    │       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  grubx64.efi
    │       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  mmx64.efi
    │       └── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  shimx64.efi
    └── [drwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:18]  grub
        ├── [drwxr-xr-x Dec 12  2022]  fonts
        │   └── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  unicode.pf2
        ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Aug  9  2022]  gfxblacklist.txt
        ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:18]  grub.cfg
        ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:39]  grubenv
        ├── [drwxr-xr-x Oct 15 16:47]  i386-pc
        ├── [drwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  locale
        │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  en_AU.mo
        │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  en_CA.mo
        │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  en_GB.mo
        │   └── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  en@quot.mo
        ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Jun 28 12:04]  unicode.pf2
        └── [drwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  x86_64-efi
            ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  acpi.mod
            ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  adler32.mod
            ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  affs.mod
    .
    .
    .
            ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  zfscrypt.mod
            ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  zfsinfo.mod
            ├── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  zfs.mod
            └── [-rwxr-xr-x Oct 17 16:19]  zstd.mod
     
    8 directories, 295 files
```

Comment: Edit your post and add the output of `$ blkid` to  it. It should state UUID's for your disks/partitions.

Comment: These are the messages that should be of concern: `Warning: didn't find any valid initrd or kernel.` Does this shed any light? https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues/60

Comment: @Hannu  that information is present (mid way) down the output from boot-repair.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that article looks similar. However, I'm not sure the situation is identical. When I tried the commands "to recover" as shown, I got an error that bpool was already mounted. Sure enough, the `mount` command shows it at `/boot`. All the kernel and initrd files are there -- just no `efi` or `grub` directories.

Since I followed the instructions, the mount points are blown away and I'm afraid to reboot now.

Comment: Ahh... missed that there was scrollable text, now I see that you have luks-partitions; IMO that might be part of the problem - no experience there though.

Comment: The luks partition was for swap. It is disabled in the `fstab`. But it does prevent me from using the typical repair tools that won't proceed unless they can see inside. Thanks for looking though!

Comment: Your EFI partition (?) nvme0n1p1 seems empty, except for a grub.cfg. Expected to see EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi, etc. as well as the grub.cfg (which should only be a few lines importing the maintained grub.cfg from /boot/grub). Workaround, put your boot commands into /etc/grub.d/40_custom and rerun update-grub (make a menuentry for them).  Try to reinstall grub, ensure the FAT is mounted at /boot/efi, then sudo grub-install.

Comment: The ZFS `bpool` is mounted to `/boot` then the  EFI partition `UUID=623E-2F76` is mounted at `/boot/efi`. I tried your suggestion of editing the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file, `update-grub`, `grub-install`. After rebooting, the grub menu is still devoid of anything but the item to enter the UEFI firmware.

Comment: Check that /boot/grub/grub.cfg after your update-grub has the modification.  Check that the EFI partition has a directory structure like EFI/ubuntu/ and EFI/Boot  .Check that EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg has the UUID of the Ubuntu root, and imports the /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  Likely, the EFI's grub.cfg does not have the import and only has the firmware menu item.  Not familiar with logical partitions, but the problem should be findable.

Comment: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has the 40_custom changes. EFI layout is shown above in the main body of my question now. Does it look right? The ubuntu root is mounted from the ZFS `rpool` (by some behind the scenes magic) and has a different UUID than the vfat drive mounted underneath `/boot` holding the `efi` directory. Is that significant?

Comment: I confirmed that the problem of https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues/60 does not apply here as the `/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/bpool` file is already present and doesn't need to be recreated. Somehow, I feel like there is an ordering problem with the boot but I don't know how to debug that if true.

Comment: Your `fstab` on `nvme0n1p4` looks super strange, I cannot see an entry for your `/`-partition.

Comment: The `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file is now working. I needed some extra syntax to create the menu entry which I was missing. That entry called `special boot` now appears in the grub menu at boot time. This tells me that the process of `update-grub` followed by `grub-install` works. I also changed '/etc/default/grub` to specify the second menu entry (from `40_custom`) as the default to use after the selection timeout expires. Maybe my system (from date of installation) had a special `40_custom` file and it got overwritten during a system update??? Will have to check that out in a backup.

Comment: @mook765 yeah that threw me for a loop as well. I believe the ZFS file system is mounted by another mechanism and involves this grub command `linux /BOOT/ubuntu_6usaiw/@/vmlinuz root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw boot=zfs`

Comment: Not sure if what you're seeing is related, but I had a similar boot order problem because of the way GRUB was generating things. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432645/ubuntu-22-04-boot-order-prefers-low-latency-over-generic-kernel/1432730#1432730

Comment: Thanks @Ken. I checked it out and that doesn't appear (to my untrained eye) to be the issue. Thanks for looking! `update-grub` does find a few generic kernels but doesn't make menus for them. For example it finds: `Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_6usaiw`

Comment: The `/etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs` script appears to be the culprit in generating the warnings I see from `update-grub`.  The ZFS pools are encrypted (but mounted and viewable) so i wonder if a script is looking at them and simply can't decrypt them so it barfs and continues. So, no menu entries get made for the `10_linux_zfs` execution.

Comment: I looked at my own 40_custom file and saw a note I left to myself:

# Adding a menu entry here places a menu entry at the bottom of 
# the GRUB selection list. Putting a menu in a custom file named 09_linux
# will insert a menu entry at the top of the GRUB selection list.

FYI, I found a lot of good info in the grub man pages when I was messing around with my own grub issues.

Comment: @ken good tip. I've been consuming web pages reporting similar problems to mine, but hadn't hit the basics yet.

Comment: I fired up the bash debugger and worked on hunting down the problem in 10_linux_zfs. I have discovered that the warning messages I see about missing initrd and vmlinuz kernels comes from ZFS snapshots being scanned that have empty boot/efi and boot/grub directories. I'm not sure why scanning old snapshots is beneficial in assembling the Grub menu. Haven't locked down the consequence of this scanning yet.